# How to find records by searching date and hour

Tags: mongodb, date, mongoose, timestamp, find

I need to retrieve all records from 10/22/2019 created after 3:00 pm until 10/23/2019 created before 3:00 pm

how can I do this?

I tried the following code without knowing if it would work

```js
db.Documents.find({
    "createdAt" : 
    {     
        $gte:   new Date(new Date(2019, 10, 24).setHours(14,59,59)),
        $lt :  new Date(new Date(2019, 10, 25).setHours(15,00,00))    
    }
})
```

Comment: `.setUTCHours()`. That's the mistake. `setHours()` will take local time, and unless you actually meant that then you're probably getting erroneous results. Otherwise, what's the actual problem? You don't really state that in your question. Perhaps if you still cannot work it out, then provide a small sample of data and what you actually expect as a result.

Comment: Also `new Date(2019, 10, 24)` also has the same "localtime" issue, and you would do instead `new Date("2019-10-24")`. Since you basically have hardcoded values anyway then it's basically unclear why you don't just do `new Date("2019-10-24T15:00:00Z")`

Comment: apparently that worked out `{$gte: new Date ("2019-10-24T14:59:59Z"), $lt: new Date ("2019-10-25T15:00:00Z")}`